# Why is the CSS not rendered when using onload event in the body tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `<body onload="myFunction()">` in my html page. In the head's tag I have integrated a css file using the tag link.

However, myFunction is executed correctly but the css looks like not working correctly. I dont why? Can someone explain me the reason please?

```js
function myFunction(){

    document.write(" <h1> Have good day</h1>")
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    border: 3px dotted red;
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>


  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>page0</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
 

</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">

 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) replaces the contents of the document, so your stylesheet gets wiped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the comment is correct that `document.write` replaces the content of your entire document. As such your entire DOM is lost and the browser renders your content in quirks mode.

To fix your code you should use another writing method to write in your body. Use a Selector that selects the body tag:
`document.body` > `document.querySelector('body')` > `getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`

Then use an `eventListener` as a trigger or a `defer`-attribute instead of the `onload`-attribute. Both will execute the script only after the DOM-Content is loaded.

defer: `<script defer></script>`
eventListener: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ... })`

AFter that, you can use a method to include the content with either `appendChild` method or the `insertAdjacentHTML` method. You should not use the `innerHTML` method as the other answer shows as it is much slower and will keep you open to XSS-Injection Attacks.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<h1> Have good day</h1>');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  border: 3px dotted red;
  padding: 0 2em 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>page0</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

PS: Remember that you can remove either the `defer`-attribute or the `eventListener` from the example. Only one is needed.